# How to solve this django webpage issue

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. I created an App called Programador related with another App called Proceso, when I try to run the App Programador in the Admin website shows me the next error:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
15                      {% endif %}
16                  </label>
17                  <div class="{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} col-auto  fieldBox {% else %} col-sm-10 {% endif %}
18                               {% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}
19                               {% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}
20                               {% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden {% endif %}
21                               {% if field.is_checkcard %} checkcard-row{% endif %}">
22                      {% if field.is_readonly %}
23                          <div class="readonly" style="margin-top: 7px;">{{ field.contents }}</div>
24                      {% else %}
25                          {{ field.field }}
26                      {% endif %}
27                      <div class="help-block red">
28                          {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
29                      </div>
30                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
31                          <div class="help-block">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
32                      {% endif %}
33                      <div class="help-block text-red">
34                          {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
35                      </div>
```

This is the code from Programador:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.Proceso import Proceso


class Programador(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    organizacion = models.CharField(verbose_name='Organización', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    estado = models.CharField(verbose_name='Organización', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo', null=True)
    proceso_ID = models.ForeignKey(Proceso, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Proceso ID',blank=True, null=True)
    programado = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo', null=True)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha inicio', null=True, blank=True)
    hora_inicio = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Hora inicio', null=True, blank=True)
    frecuencia = models.CharField(verbose_name='Frecuencia', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    intervalo = models.CharField(verbose_name='Intervalo', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha fin', null=True, blank=True)
    hora_fin = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Hora fin', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.estado

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Programador"
        verbose_name_plural = "Programadores"
        db_table = 'core_programador_programador'
        ordering = ['id']
```

And the code from Proceso:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Proceso(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True, verbose_name='Uuid')
    organizacion = models.CharField(verbose_name='Organización', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo', null=True)
    indetificador = models.CharField(verbose_name='Identificador', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre_clase = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre Clase', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        ordering = [id]
        verbose_name = "Proceso"
        verbose_name_plural = "Procesos"
        db_table = 'core_programador_proceso'
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.Proceso import Proceso
from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.Programador import Programador
admin.site.register(Proceso)
admin.site.register(Programador)
```

Does anyone know why I have this error?
Thank you!

Comment: and the code in the admin.py file?

Comment: I posted it now. Thanks

Comment: If your process model and programmer are in the same file model, why are you importing it?

Comment: You are tring to get an element from a method. Probably in views.py. can you share it?